# Migrating from SVN multi-repo to GIT

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm total newbie in git-svn bridge and faced a task to migrate from SVN repo to GIT. SVN structure looks really terribly:

```
root
  base
    server
      core
         branch
         tags
         trunk
      webapp
         branch
         tags
         trunk
       ....
    client
      core
         branch
         tags
         trunk
      ....
    ....
  ....
```

As a "talented svn migrate-master", I executed `git svn clone ..../root` and cloned the whole repository. I have no branches visible to GIT:

`$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/git-svn`

I can easily navigate to `root-base-server-core-branch-my-awesome-branch` and it looks like regular folder.

How to continue svn2git conversation? Looks like I should start from scratch but cloning this evil took one week and I don't want to wait again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple svn projects in that repo.  Do you want to combine them in git?
You may want to look into making a separate git repository for client, core and webapp.

Look into git svn clone's `--branches`, it can take multiple wildcards, which you may need with that terrible svn structure. Something like `--branches=*/*/*/*/branch/*`

You can also use multiple `--branches` as in `--branches=coked/out/path/branch/* --branches=totally/messed/up/path/branches/*`

From the help:

> ```
>        -T<trunk_subdir>, --trunk=<trunk_subdir>, -t<tags_subdir>, --tags=<tags_subdir>, -b<branches_subdir>,
>        --branches=<branches_subdir>, -s, --stdlayout
>            These are optional command-line options for init. Each of these flags can point to a relative repository path
>            (--tags=project/tags) or a full url (--tags=https://foo.org/project/tags). You can specify more than one --tags and/or
>            --branches options, in case your Subversion repository places tags or branches under multiple paths. The option
>            --stdlayout is a shorthand way of setting trunk,tags,branches as the relative paths, which is the Subversion default. If
>            any of the other options are given as well, they take precedence.
> ```